# Создание радио кнопок в pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как работать с радиокнопками в PyQt5 чтоб они так же функцианировали как и в tkinter что то по типу вот этого

```
var = IntVar()
var.set(0)
rad0 = Radiobutton(windows_2, variable=var, justify=LEFT,  value=1,height=2)
rad1 = Radiobutton(windows_2, variable=var, justify=LEFT,  value=2,height=2)
rad2 = Radiobutton(windows_2, variable=var, justify=LEFT,  value=3,height=2)
rad0.place(x=0,y=125)
rad1.place(x=0,y=175)
rad2.place(x=0,y=235)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Qt для этого есть класс [QRadioButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qradiobutton.html):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QLabel('Current')

        self.radio_button_1 = QRadioButton('1')
        self.radio_button_1.setChecked(True)

        self.radio_button_2 = QRadioButton('2')
        self.radio_button_3 = QRadioButton('3')

        self.button_group = QButtonGroup()
        self.button_group.addButton(self.radio_button_1)
        self.button_group.addButton(self.radio_button_2)
        self.button_group.addButton(self.radio_button_3)

        self.button_group.buttonClicked.connect(self._on_radio_button_clicked)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.radio_button_1)
        layout.addWidget(self.radio_button_2)
        layout.addWidget(self.radio_button_3)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def _on_radio_button_clicked(self, button):
        print(button)
        self.label.setText('Current: ' + button.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если есть потребность связать с кнопкой какие-то данные, то можно сделать простенький словарь, где ключом будет кнопка:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
...
        self.button_by_data = {
            self.radio_button_1: 'Data 1',
            self.radio_button_2: [1, 2, 3],
            self.radio_button_3: 42,
        }
...
```

А после в `_on_radio_button_clicked` поменять на `print(button, self.button_by_data[button])`

И при клике в консоли будет подобная строка:

```
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QRadioButton object at 0x00000000028F6A68> [1, 2, 3]
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QRadioButton object at 0x00000000028F69D8> Data 1
```

Comment: А в pyqt5 есть параметр в радиокнопках по типу variable? Ну пример у меня 3 радиокнопки в которых уже записаны данные и мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку(именно конкретно кнопку, не радиокнопку)  у меня выводился номер кнопки а не её название?

Comment: Так вроде бы нет. У виджетов есть метод `setProperty`, но с ним нужно осторожнее, т.к. его изменение может поменять содержимое виджета, например если через `setProperty` указать "text". В `QButtonGroup` при добавлении кнопки можно указывать ее id, по умолчанию туда `-1` добавляется, а при клике тот id получить: `self.button_group.id(button)` либо воспользоваться `self.button_by_data`

Comment: а как объявлять этот id ?

Comment: @Дмитрий
`self.button_group.addButton(self.radio_button_1, 1) self.button_group.addButton(self.radio_button_2, 2) ...` Быстрее было вам самому открыть спеку по QButtonGroup и посмотреть, чем дожидаться ответа )